# Physics simulation without the objects falling down

Tags: physics, rigidbody

I am trying to apply rigid body physics to objects but do not want them to fall down when the animation is playing. They should stay in their positions but react to other rigid bodies. Please refer to the video for an example. I wonder if something similar can be achieved in Blender. Thank you!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZo8rFPOQ14

[image]

Comment: If these RBs are already constrained to the central sphere, just set your gravity to 0.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. That's seems to be an interesting solution. Let me try to experiment with constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rigid bodies and force fields:

[image]

Give your sphere a *Physics > Rigid Body, Type > Passive*, enable the *Settings > Animated* option. Create your small objects, give them *Physics > Rigid Body, Type > Active*. Create 2 *Force Fields* or more at the same position as the sphere, like for example a *Force Field > Force* and a *Turbulence*, parent them to the sphere. Give them highly negative *Strenghts*. Animate the sphere. In the *Scene* panel cut the *Gravity* option, and under *Rigid Body World > Cache* make the simulation begin before frame 0 and click on *Bake*.

Comment: Amazing! This is a very interesting solution and it works too. Thank you very much @moonboots.